# What Exactly is a Model Relative to the ModelAndView Class in Spring

Tags: java, spring

What exactly does the "Model" part mean? Is it the same as the domain model? I've read that it's a map, but I'm having a hard time understanding the concept.

Comment: where did you read it? provide more details.

Comment: I read it in Spring's official document and their javadoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always treated it as a View Model as opposed to a pure Domain Model, the `ModelAndView` class name lends itself to that distinction as well as the use of a Map to drop various bits of model data in for viewing purposes.